# Is a4 = a4paper?

Tags: geometry, paper-size

```
\documentclass[12pt,
               a4,
               twoside,
               openright]{book}
```

Above is from my university master thesis template, I checked other schools templates, they all use a4paper, is `a4`=`a4paper`?
And I do not find `geometry` in my template, does it mean my template uses default a4 size? Is there a standard(or widely accepted) size for thesis?

Comment: You should get a warning about an unused option `a4`? `a4paper` is the option

Comment: No, it isn't the same. The option `a4` is not defined for the `book` class (so it does nothing, except issuing a warning), whereas `a4paper` is.

Comment: By the way, you are asking more than question. Are you sure that `a4` is in the `documentclass` option list, not `\usepackage{a4}`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am sure, I just exactly copy the first line in my template.So you think my template has problem? From my basic knowledge about latex I feel my template is a kind of unnormal...

Comment: Are there other university specific packages being loaded later in the preamble?  If so the `a4` option might be processed there.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Here is the only other one package related with a4 I find in preamble, \usepackage[frame,a4,center]{crop}, but this one is not a definition either...

Comment: According to the package documentation, `a4` _is_ a standard option for `crop`.  However, what I really meant was that options to `\documentclass` are made available to all the other packages loaded. E.g. `a4` as option to documentclass followed simply by `\usepackage{crop}` means `a4` is passed to `crop` too.  Thus other packages you are loading could be using the option.

Comment: You should mention this to the maintainer of the template if you can. Depending on how people configure their system, either A4 or (US) leterpaper is the default size.  If they try to print the thesis subsequently, they might be in for a (small) surprise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "short" options `a4`, `letter`, `a5`, ... are not defined, neither in standard classes like `article`, `book` etc., nor in the package `geometry`. The proper options are `a4paper`, `letterpaper`, `a5paper`, ...

If this is the template your university proposed, then your university have obviously quite small knowledge of LaTeX.

For the standard paper size, this is something your university has to set up, I've seen theses on A4, Letter, B5 and maybe other paper sizes as well.

Comment: In the meantime, I've seen a4 option on many more places, such as http://imft.ftn.uns.ac.rs/math/cms/uploads/Main/LAP_2021_Template.tex. Is it possible that it _was_ a valid option a long time ago, and was just copy-pasted into newer and newer documents?